# Displaying LaTeX in WP8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, latex, mathjax

I have a few math formulas which I want to display in the app and they are in .tex format. So far I've found no plug-ins that render LaTeX in WP8.

So I tried to display it in an HTML page and show the HTML page in a WebView control. I gave "CodeCogs LaTeX Engine" a try but it would convert the formulas to images and then display it, limiting the ability to change font-size or colors. Also, it worked online.

Then I tried MathJAX. It worked perfectly. The font-size is changeable and colors too. But it works online and when I try to download it's offline version, it gives me a large bunch of .js file that are about 35 MB. I don't want my app to be that large. (I haven't yet tested if this set-up works well on the phone's browser too).

Please let me know any suggestions on how to go about this. Is there any direct way to render LaTeX in WP8?

Comment: You won't need all of MathJax. See [this guide](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-docs/wiki/Guide%3A-reducing-size-of-a-mathjax-installation) for how to reduce the footprint by choosing the MathJax components you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a finite set of formulas bundled with the app, the easiest way would be to render them in Windows, make "screenshots" and embed the images in your app.

Comment: That is how my app currently works. I was thinking of moving those formulas from images to a .tex file so I could give the user option to select font size and color. And it would allow zooming in without blur